# Trouble making text flush left and flush right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to flush left and flush right a "From" and "To" addresses on a page. Here is my LaTeX:

```
%tutorial @: https://www.overleaf.com/20012832vhybmwjdyjqt#/73357884/

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[LO]{FOR OFFICIAL USE ONLY}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{Town1 to Town2}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} %turns off numbering of sections

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\center

\textsc{\LARGE Company Corp.}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large Project Number: 1}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large For Official Use Only}\\[0.5cm]

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Shipping Report}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1cm]

\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{From}\\
\textsc{Company}\\
First Name\\
Street\\
Town
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{To} \\
\textsc{Attn: Guy}\\
Street\\
Town\\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[1cm]

\end{titlepage}
```

Which comes out looking like this:

```
From
First Name
Street 
Town   
                       To
                       Attn: Guy
                       Street
                       Town
```

I would like it so that From is flush left and To is flush right on the same line as From, instead of staggered as you see here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have only provided a snippet, not a complete, small working example.  When I convert your snippet into a working example, I do not get the behavior you describe.  Help us to help you by providing a complete working example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document} 
{\large\noindent\Longunderstack[l]{
\emph{From}\\
\textsc{Company}\\
First Name\\
Street\\
Town}\hfill\Longunderstack[r]{
\emph{To} \\
\textsc{Attn: Guy}\\
Street\\
Town\\
}}\vspace{\baselineskip}

Normalsize text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
 \large
\emph{From}\\
\textsc{Company}\\
First Name\\
Street\\
Town
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{flushright}
 \large
\emph{To} \\
\textsc{Attn: Guy}\\
Street\\
Town\\
\end{flushright}

\end{minipage}\\[1cm]
\end{document}
```